# Ruby on Rails application in a docker container docker compose build error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

when I try to call `docker-compose build` for ROR project, I have following error

`ERROR: Service 'rails' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install -j 20' returned a non-zero code: 20`

any ideas what could be the problem or how I should start investigating it? Where can I start from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the error was related to Gemfile.lock file. Found in the `bundle` error codes description: https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/3f0638c6c8d340c2f2405ecb84eb3b39c433e36e/lib/bundler/errors.rb#L51